# Fixing a meeting room function schedule with double and triple bookings to determine space usage

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I need to calculate the total amount of time each group uses a meeting space. But the data set has double and triple booking, so I think I need to fix the data first. Disclosure: My coding experience consists solely of  working through a few Dataquest courses, and this is my first stackoverflow posting, so I apologize for errors and transgressions.

Each line of the data set contains the group ID and a start and end time. It also includes the booking type, ie. reserved, meeting, etc. Generally, the staff reserve a space for the entire period, which would create a single line, and then add multiple lines for each individual function when the details are known. They should segment the original reserved line so it's only holding space in between functions, but instead they double book the space, so I need to add multiple lines for these interim RES holds, based on the actual holds.

Here's what the data basically looks like:

Existing data:

```py
functions = [['Function', 'Group', 'FunctionType', 'StartTime', 'EndTime'],
[01,01,'RES',2019/10/04 07:00,2019/10/06 17:00],
[02,01,'MTG',2019/10/05 09:00,2019/10/05 12:00],
[03,01,'LUN',2019/10/05 12:30,2019/10/05 13:30],
[04,01,'MTG',2019/10/05 14:00,2019/10/05 17:00],
[05,01,'MTG',2019/10/06 09:00,2019/10/06 12:00]]
```

I've tried to iterate using a for loop:

```py
for index, row in enumerate(functions):
    last_row_index = len(functions) - 1

    if index == last_row_index:
        pass
    else:
        current_index = index
        next_index = index + 1

    if row[3] <= functions[next_index][2]:
        next
    elif row[4] == 'RES' or row[6] < functions[next_index][6]:
        copied_current_row = row.copy()
        row[3] = functions[next_index][2]
        copied_current_row[2] = functions[next_index][3] 
        functions.append(copied_current_row)
```

There seems to be a logical problem in here, because that last append line seems to put the program into some kind of loop and I have to manually interrupt it. So I'm sure it's obvious to someone experienced, but I'm pretty new.

The reason I've done the comparison to see if a function is RES is that reserved should be subordinate to actual functions. But sometimes there are overlaps between actual functions, so I'll need to create another comparison to decide which one takes precedence, but this is where I'm starting.

How I (think) I want it to end up:

```py
[['Function', 'Group', 'FunctionType', 'StartTime', 'EndTime'],
[01,01,'RES',2019/10/04 07:00,2019/10/05 09:00],
[02,01,'MTG',2019/10/05 09:00,2019/10/05 12:00],
[01,01,'RES',2019/10/05 12:00,2019/10/05 12:30],
[03,01,'LUN',2019/10/05 12:30,2019/10/05 13:30],
[01,01,'RES',2019/10/05 13:30,2019/10/05 14:00],
[04,01,'MTG',2019/10/05 14:00,2019/10/05 17:00],
[01,01,'RES',2019/10/05 14:00,2019/10/06 09:00],
[05,01,'MTG',2019/10/06 09:00,2019/10/06 12:00],
[01,01,'RES',2019/10/06 12:00,2019/10/06 17:00]]
```

This way, I could do a simple calculation of elapsed time for each function line and add it up to see how much time they had the space booked for.

What I'm looking for here is just some direction I should pursue, and I'm definitely not expecting anyone to do the work for me. For example, am I on the right path here, or would it be better to use pandas and vectorized functions? If I can get the basic direction right, I think I can muddle through the specifics.

Thank-you very much,
AF

Comment: (1) It is not recommended to modify a structure (here: `functions`) while you iterate over it with `for`. Better create a new list and copy entries from the old list (maybe modified) step by step and `append` new entries where necessary. (2) The `next` line should therefore consist of such an append and a `continue` instead. (3) If the list has at most a few 10000 entries pure Python is fast enough and in my opinion easier than vectorization with pandas or similar.

Comment: Thank-you for the feedback, Michael. I had read something about not altering the structure I'm iterating over, so that's valuable to have confirmed. And the first time I run this algorithm, there will be more than 10,000 entries, but once the historical dates are fixed, the daily runs will be far less, so this is good to know.